# How to Transfer an image from one scene to another

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to take a screenshot of an object and then show it as a preview in the order form(Another scene ) in unity.

I have used the Native Gallery asset to save the screenshot to the gallery. But I am unsure how to display the image in the next scene.

Is there a way to do this? Or maybe send the image to the next scene?

Update:

I tried adding the DontDestroyOnLoad script to the game object associated with taking the screenshot,but the screenshot is not being shown in the second scene. Here is my code

```
void Start()
{
    DontDestroyOnLoad(transform.gameObject);

}
```

and I called the following function from the scene change script

```
void Start()
{
    GameObject thePlayer = GameObject.Find("screenshotGameObject");
    TakeScreenshot playerScript = thePlayer.GetComponent<TakeScreenshot>();
    Screenshot = playerScript.ss;
}
```

The script I use to take screenshot

```
public class TakeScreenshot : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField]
    public Text debugText;
    public GameObject ScreenshotImage;


    //protected const string MEDIA_STORE_IMAGE_MEDIA = "android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media";
    //protected static AndroidJavaObject m_Activity;

    public void TakeAShot()
    {
        StartCoroutine(TakeScreenshotAndSave());
    }


    IEnumerator TakeScreenshotAndSave()
    {
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();

        Texture2D ss = new Texture2D(Screen.width, Screen.height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        ss.ReadPixels(new Rect(0, 0, Screen.width, Screen.height), 0, 0);
        ss.Apply();
        NativeGallery.Permission permission = NativeGallery.CheckPermission();
        NativeGallery.RequestPermission();
        if (permission == NativeGallery.Permission.Denied)
        {
            NativeGallery.OpenSettings();
        }

        else if(permission == NativeGallery.Permission.Granted)
        {
            // Save the screenshot to Gallery/Photos
            Debug.Log("Permission result: " + NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(ss, "Boflora", "Image.png"));

            //debugText.text = "Permission result: " + NativeGallery.SaveImageToGallery(ss, "GalleryTest", "Image.png");
            // To avoid memory leaks
            //Destroy(ss);

        }

        StartCoroutine(ShowAndHide(1.0f)); // 1 second

    }
    IEnumerator ShowAndHide(float delay)
    {
        ScreenshotImage.SetActive(true);
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(delay);
        ScreenshotImage.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: There are a number of ways to send/keep an object for the next scene, what have you tried, what have you done, What have you look at and dismissed...

Comment: I don't know any method to transfer a picture or access it from gallery. I am not talking about a object,but a screenshot that is taken dynamically on a scene. Kindly help

Comment: well, everything is an object, in c# therefore in unity so the way to transfer anything between scenes could apply

Comment: First question how you are talking the screenshot? As I can understand and what I've scean so far it should be a render texture if this is the case you can assign the same render testure to any script of scean#2 and you can use that.

Comment: @BugFinder,I tried that approach and updated the question, still not working

Comment: @Ankit, I am using the NativeGallery plugin from the unity asset library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try saving the image in a script and put that script on a gameobject and use dont destroy on load function. you can have your image in the next scene

Comment: Hi,I tried doing that,but somehow the picture is not available in the second scene,could you check what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there, can you please confirm whether you are using that screen shot in a canvas as a game object or as a texture in the assets?

Comment: I am capturing the screenshot using a script, which is embedded into a gameobject on scene

Comment: I think the issue is because I am capturing a texture 2D in script and trying to put into an image in canvas in the next scene

Comment: There can be two methods for your scenario : 
1. You can save the screen shot in your asset/resources folder whenever the screenshot is taken, in this way it can be used anywhere in the entire game (by name) (you can then fetch that screenshot by resources.load() method)
2. secondly whenever the screenshot is taken, you can pass that ss in another script in the scene like "screenshot holder" that saves your screenshot in an array or a game object of type sprite or texture etc and you can simple take that "screenshot holder" game object in another scene by dont destroy on load method.

Comment: hi,I will try the second method first,could you show me how to assign the texture to an image in cavas? (I am sorry for asking something unrelated to the question)

Screenshot.sprite = Sprite.Create(playerScript.ss, new Rect(0.0f, 0.0f, playerScript.ss.width, playerScript.ss.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f), 100.0f);

This is what I tried,but not working

Comment: Yeah sure, lets suppose you have saved you screenshot as a sprite in your screenshot handler script ...
Now create a game object under your canvas >add an image component on it > assign the "screenshot handler image" to this image component and reset the position if necessary....
Remember, only sprites are assigned to image component, textures are not assigned to image component, (you have to convert them to sprite)
let me know if i can help any further

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206898/discussion-between-jerin-cherian-and-arslan-mughal).

Comment: another issue I am facing now is,only the first picture taken in the app is being shown,images taken after that are not coming to the next scene